# The generating function for $1, 1, 1, 1, ...$ is $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, generating-functions

I'm told that the the generating function for the sequence $$1, 1, 1, ...$$ is $$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 +... = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n$$ which then equals to $$\frac{1}{1-x}$$ by the geometric series test.

I have a problem with this claim. The geometric series test claims that $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$ if $|x|<1$. Since we are dealing with formal power series, which have no restriction on what $x$ is, how can we boldly claim that these two expressions are equal? The expression $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is a function whereas the expression $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n$ is simply a formal power series which doesn't even have to be a well-defined function. So how can they be equal?

It gets more confusing for me!

Derivatives of formal power series are defined as $$\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n \right)' = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}.$$ I'm then told that since $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x},$$ then we have $$\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n \right)' = \left (\frac{1}{1-x} \right)' = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

My second question: the expression $$\frac{1}{1-x}$$ is a well-defined function and so its derivative makes sense from analysis. However, the generating function $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n$$  is not a well-defined function and is formally defined as a sequence. The notion of differentiation is however well-defined for generating functions. How can we then tell that these two notions of differentiation are equal to each other?

Thank you for any help. I would totally appreciate it.

Comment: A formal power series may converge in a disc $|x|<r$, $r>0$. Then it defines an analytic function on $|x|<r$. You may say that this analytic function is the generating function of your sequence.

Comment: Formal power series (in the context you're looking at in particular) are not concerned with convergence, for the simple reason that they're really just an algebraic, notational tool: we are defining operations on sequences which simply have natural notational tie-ins to how we operate on series. So why not use the more intuitive notation?

Comment: Indeed "term by term" differentiation of an infinite series deserves a particular proof... This is one of the many theorems that are established for "analytic functions theory" which can be well understood only in the equivalent framework of "(holomorphic) complex functions theory"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the germ at the origin. But the usual way to look at this is to consider $1/(1-x)$ as a division *of formal power series* $\mathbb R[[x]]$. Remember that division is defined as the inverse of multiplication.
So you can verify: $(1-x)\times(1+x+x^2+\cdots) = 1$, where the multiplication is the multiplication *of formal power series*. Formal power series are *not* functions. They cannot be evaluated in general.

Also, no matter in which ring, as long as differentiation satisfies linearity and the product rule, then the quotient rule follows. So the differentiation makes sense.

Comment: This is a very insightful answer. I have one last question and I would appreciate your answer. So do we look at $ \frac{1}{ (1-x)^2}$ as the inverse of $(1-x)^2$ in $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$, which of course may not be a function at all? Meaning that we can't just look at $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ where we can just plug in a real number and get another real number. So if someone tells me that the generating function for such and such a sequence is $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, then they are talking about a formal power series and not an actual function right?

Comment: @Hoji Right. But in case the corresponding formal power series actually converges, then it does make sense to call it a function. Even so, there are techniques that seems to "evaluate" a series, but technically constructs ring homomorphisms that "fakes it".